# Check for same ID in 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi all I have the following query to check if an ID is present in a table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tT 
     UNION 
     SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tET
     UNION 
     SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tE) AS idSearcher 
WHERE 
     idSearcher.RequestID = 120) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END AS alreadyHasID
```

This works but it doesn't seem to see if **ANY of the 3 tables** have the same ID. The above query only seems to check if **ALL of the 3 tables** has that value.

As an example the output for the query above:

```
|alreadyHasID |
+-------------+
 n
```

When it should be 'y' since, out of the 3 tables, **1 table DOES have 120**.

Running each of the 3 tables separately gives this as the output:

```
+----------+
|tT        |
+----------+
 no records

+----------+
|tET       |
+----------+
 no records

+----------+
|tE        |
+----------+
 120
```

How can this be modified in order to show a **"y"** if it finds the ID in **ANY of the 3 tables**?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return a `y` if it finds the ID in *all* tables?  Otherwise, it's already doing what you're asking.

Comment: ANY or ALL - you need to decide?

Comment: **ANY** is what I am looking for

Comment: But you stated the above query works for **ANY**

Comment: Check out my added OP example. Hope that clears it up more.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Do you not see my example in the OP?

Comment: I will bet that if you put that value in ALL tables is still does not work for you.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis 'y'

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis no. As my example shows, it returns an 'n' even though 1 of the tables (tE) does have the 120 value while the other 2 have no values.

Comment: See @SqlZim example below for the correct answer to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case 
     when exists (select 1 from tT  where RequestID = 120)
       or exists (select 1 from tTE where RequestID = 120)
       or exists (select 1 from tE  where RequestID = 120)
      then 'y'
     else 'n'
     end
```

Comment: This would be the correct answer if you changed **"and"** to **"or"**'s

Comment: @StealthRT I see. I guess there was some confusion initially about whether you wanted **all** or **any**.

Answer (score 4):

Use inner joins to filter where there is a match for ALL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
   SELECT * 
   FROM (tT INNER JOIN tET ON tT.RequestID = tET.RequestID)
      INNER JOIN tE ON tT.RequestID = tE.RequestID
   WHERE tT.RequestID = 120
) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END AS alreadyHasID
```

For ANY you do it this way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tT WHERE [RequestID] = 120) THEN 'y' 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tET WHERE RequestID = 120) THEN 'y' 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tE WHERE RequestID = 120) THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END as [alreadyHasID]
```

Comment: yes this is also the correct answer **(ANY)**. However, sqlZim solved it first.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant "to show a y if it finds the ID in ALL tables".

May be something like this:

```
select case when (
                select count(case when RequestID = 120 then 1 end)
                from (
                    select * from (select top 1 RequestID
                    from tT
                    order by ??)
                    union all
                    (select top 1 RequestID
                    from tET
                    order by ??)
                    union all
                    (select top 1 RequestID
                    from tE
                    order by ??)
                    ) as t
                ) = 3 then 'y' else 'n' end as alreadyHasID
```

Note the added order by. You should always add these when using `TOP` queries.

Comment: @Paparazzi - Oh yeah. totally missed that.

Comment: "to show a y if it finds the ID in ALL tables" should be "to show a y if it finds the ID in **ANY** table"

Comment: @StealthRT - That your own query should already be doing. See this demo - http://rextester.com/MCDLM42857

Answer (score -1):

This is so messed up
TOP is non deterministic
You are checking idSearcher.RequestID = 120 outside

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ( SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tT 
                                         UNION 
                                         SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tET
                                         UNION 
                                         SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM tE 
                                       ) AS idSearcher 
                                       WHERE idSearcher.RequestID = 120
                        ) 
            THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END AS alreadyHasID
```